# Eclipse (Kepler): committing a file deleted outside Eclipse

Tags: sync, svn, eclipse

Scenario:

- I have a project open in Eclipse.
- I delete a file in this project using a different tool than Eclipse
  (for example a `find` script or Windows Explorer)

Now, **correctly**, Eclipse will show the missing files as "Missing", and by default the "Commit" will have them *unselected*. This way if the deletion is accidental, recovery will be straightforward (just run a SVN update of the project).

It could be argued that if I *do* check the missing files and choose to Commit, then the deletion should be committed to Subversion. However, it does not happen that way. The commit is done, but the missing files, be they checked or unchecked, are ignored.

How to commit those deletions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the missing files are few or small or, however, recovery isn't a hassle:

1. Select the folder where the files were.
2. Select "Team" > "Update".
3. The files will be restored.
4. Delete the files from Eclipse, this time.
5. Select "Team" > "Commit", and Bob's your uncle.

Otherwise, the procedure is more awkward (and possibly not the correct one: yet, it works).

1. Select Team > Synchronize With Repository (Ctrl-Alt-S).
2. Open the Team Synchronisation perspective.
3. Select all the files marked by an outgoing black arrow with a "minus" sign
4. Right-click and select "Override and Commit".

The dialog that appears is **apparently** the same of an ordinary commit, and the files are still marked as "Missing", and they are all unchecked.

5. Verify the files are the correct ones, and check them.
6. Click OK.

Now, the commit is performed.

7. Return to the default perspective.